# Pine script check future bars

Tags: pine-script

In Pine Script is there any way to look into the future up to the current bar?  For example if a low of $10 was hit months ago, at that time I want to know if that was the lowest low until current bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access future bars except with a special form of `security()` calls which shouldn't be used to read prices ahead of time, as it doesn't make sense in a trading strategy.